# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rosbag' with pip

Tags: python, anaconda, ros

I am trying to install `rosbag` using pip:

`pip install python-rosbag`

But I am getting the following error:

> (base) C:\Users\santhoshe.e\annotator-master>pip install python-rosbag
>       Collecting python-rosbag
>         ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-rosbag (from versions: none)
>       ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-rosbag

How can I install `rosbag` in windows other than using `pip`? Or the `pip` I used is wrong?

Comment: [Check out this link](https://pypi.org/project/pyrosbag/) and try it: `pip2 install pyrosbag` and try with `sudo` also.

Comment: See also: [Importing Rosbag in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59794328/importing-rosbag-in-python-3)

Comment: Try `pip install bagpy`

Answer (score 3):

`pyrosbag` is actually a different package from `rosbag`.

The right way should be

```
conda install -c conda-forge ros-rosbag
```

After that, you can run `import rosbag` in Python.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be this:

```
pip install pyrosbag
```

Comment: I run that command.Again it is showing the same error ModuleNotFound

Comment: @BinduMachani it works fine for me, what version of pip are you using, `pip --version`

Comment: I am using pip version 19.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Try this to install pyrosbag using pip:

```
pip install pyrosbag
```

Now in the docs, the [Usage page](https://pyrosbag.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) shows the import command as:

```
import pyrosbag
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to install ros noetic (I installed the desktop-full version).
See link: http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu

If you then source the setup script for ros via the following command:
`source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash`

Python should be able to import rosbag.

Answer (score 0):

Actually for rosbag, it is not very easy to install by using pip.

However you can use installation steps defined in ROS wiki.

But it is not done after installing rosbag, you should also add PYTHONPATH for the rosbag in your interpreter. Which can be done by simply selecting File>Settings>Project Interpreter and click the gear right next to your interpreter.

After that you will see two options : Add/ShowAll. Go with Show All and on the window that opened, on the right hand side, you will see +,-,..., a symbol that shows the paths for the selected interpreter (the symbol listed at the end)

Under these paths you should also define the path that you installed ros. For me, the path is :

/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages