# Importing Rosbag in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ros, ros2, rosbag

I'm trying to read rosbag files from Python 3.
I installed ROS2 (Eloquent Elusor), which should support Python 3.

When I run

```
import rosbag
bag = rosbag.Bag('test.bag')
```

from Python 2.7, it works.
When I try the same in Python 3, I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rosbag'
```

I also tried things like: `sudo apt install python-rosbag`, `sudo apt install python3-rospkg` and `pip3 install rospkg`, but they don't help.

What should I do to open a rosbag file from Python 3?

[EDIT]
This is the output after calling `pip3 install rospkg`:

```
Requirement already satisfied: rospkg in ./rosbag-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: catkin-pkg in ./rosbag-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from rospkg)
Requirement already satisfied: distro in ./rosbag-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from rospkg)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML in ./rosbag-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from rospkg)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing in ./rosbag-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from catkin-pkg->rospkg)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in ./rosbag-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from catkin-pkg->rospkg)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils in ./rosbag-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from catkin-pkg->rospkg)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./rosbag-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-dateutil->catkin-pkg->rospkg)
```

Comment: It is my understanding that the rosbag library is only python2.7 and from what i have been able to research does not exist on Python3 yet. pyrosbag is not a stable library and i would not suggest it.There are a couple tutorials to use python2.7 libs in python3 though this feels kind of hacky to me. im in the same boat as  you at the moment.

Comment: See also: [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rosbag' with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57254026/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-rosbag-with-pip)

Comment: https://jmscslgroup.github.io/bagpy/index.html

Comment: @castaway2000 very strange. I have a conda environment with python 3.7.10 and rosbag installed no problem.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `bagpy` package to read the .bag file in Python. It can be installed using pip

```
pip install bagpy
```

Brief documentation is at https://jmscslgroup.github.io/bagpy/

Following are example code-snippets:

```
import bagpy
from bagpy import bagreader

b = bagreader('09-23-59.bag')

# get the list of topics
print(b.topic_table)

# get all the messages of type velocity
velmsgs   = b.vel_data()
veldf = pd.read_csv(velmsgs[0])
plt.plot(veldf['Time'], veldf['linear.x'])

# quickly plot velocities
b.plot_vel(save_fig=True)

# you can animate a timeseries data
bagpy.animate_timeseries(veldf['Time'], veldf['linear.x'], title='Velocity Timeseries Plot')
```

Comment: How does `bagreader`'s implementation get away with using `import rosbag` underneath and how does it install it?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question.

Comment: Doing `pip3 install bagpy` does indeed some to now allow me to do `import rosbag` in Python3. I'm not sure how this works, but it does seem to work.

Comment: I added [my own answer with my comment above, and more detail, here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69368883/4561887).

Answer (score 5):

### TLDR;

Run this:

```sh
pip3 install bagpy
# OR, if that ends up failing in the end due to a "Permission denied" error, 
# do this:
sudo pip3 install bagpy
```

Now this will work in your Python 3 script:

```py
import rosbag
```

...so long as you have the correct hash-bang at the top of your Python 3 file, such as this one:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

### Details

I have written [`ros_readbagfile`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/ros_readbagfile.py) and this ROS tutorial here: [Reading messages from a bag file](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/reading%20msgs%20from%20a%20bag%20file), and this `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rosbag'` error seems to come up a lot:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "./ros_readbagfile", line 50, in <module>
>     import rosbag
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rosbag'
> ```

The solution to get `import rosbag` to work in Python 3 seems to be:

```sh
pip3 install bagpy
```

Now `import rosbag` works, and therefore, so does [my `ros_readbagfile` script](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/ros_readbagfile.py).

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65386862/4561887), you can apparently also do:

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge ros-rosbag
```

...but I haven't tried that.

If you have run `pip3 install bagpy` and it fails to complete due to permissions errors:

> ```
> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
> ```

...then try using `sudo` as well:

```sh
sudo pip3 install bagpy
```

Now, assuming that worked, if `import rosbag` still doesn't work, then it may be because `pip3 install bagpy` installed `bagpy` (and `rosbag`) *for a different binary executable of Python3 than what your script is calling via its hash-bang line at the top.* To see if that's the case, run `which python3` and use that path at the top of your Python3 script. Ex: my `which python3` output is:

> ```
> /usr/bin/python3
> ```

So, my hashbang (shebang) at the top of my Python3 script should be:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Other common paths may include:

> ```
> /usr/local/bin/python3
> ```

Or (BEST in this case), to let your environment choose the python3 executable for you, use this hash-bang at the top of your Python 3 file instead:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

This is what I now use at the top of my [ros_readbagfile.py](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/ros_readbagfile.py) script.

### Other references:

1. [my own comment and this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59794328/importing-rosbag-in-python-3#comment121818346_64310922)
2. [cross-linked on the ROS site] https://answers.ros.org/question/12307/no-module-named-rosbag-error/?answer=387606#post-id-387606

Answer (score 2):

I've written a pure python3 module for importing rosbag data. It's standalone - no ROS installation required. It only works for a selected subset of the message types but it should serve as an example which you can follow to unpack the message types that you're interested in:
https://github.com/event-driven-robotics/importRosbag

Answer (score 2):

To use the standard `rosbag` library, you have two options:

1. [Set up ROS](https://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation) and install it via apt:

```
sudo apt install ros-$ROS_DISTRO-rosbag ros-$ROS_DISTRO-roslz4
source /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash
```

2. Install it as a regular Python package from pip, albeit not from the regular PyPI index:

```
pip install rosbag roslz4 --extra-index-url https://rospypi.github.io/simple/
```

Note that if you are have already sourced `/opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash`, which adds the ROS Python packages to `PYTHONPATH`, you might need to do `unset PYTHONPATH` first for the pip-installed package to be used. This is especially important if you are using Python from within a virtualenv or a Conda environment.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook it says that you have to do the following in pip3 to make rosbag work:

```sh
pip3 install pycryptodomex python-gnupg
```

Worked for me so far. Hope that might help all others as well.

Setup:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- ROS Melodic
- Python3

Answer (score -3):

Try this and it will work:

```
pip3 install pyrosbag
```

Comment: pyrosbag is not the same package as OP is requesting.

Comment: if you check pyrosbag you will see it is what he requested.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65386862/4561887